# Visual Studio 2017 and webpack typescript errors

Tags: visual-studio, angular, webpack

Is there a way for Visual Studio to be aware of typescript errors when building with webpack? 
Currently, with latest SPA templates for .NET Core 2.0 and Angular 2, webpack is used for building typescript files, which works great except that now all compile time errors (typescript errors) are shown in the browser in contrast to standard building flow, where are compile time errors are shown in "Error List" window - which is much better IMHO, because I don't have manually to locate build errors, all I need to do is to double click.

**Edit**

As some people find this question useful, let me update this question and actually given an answer to it. Currently (as of 3/6/2018) Visual Studio is a bit obsolete IMHO (for SPA applications). Using Visual Studio Code makes much more sense now and there is a terminal window that can be used to check build errors (with webpack-devServer and hot builds/autosave features turned on).